# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in not working for me. I want to go back

Tags: updates

My pc wanted to upgrade to 16.04 LTS, and now it shuts off if I leave it for more than 5 minutes.  I called Verizon, they said "does not support ubuntu 16.04."  I called Dell and they said I need a new motherboard.  I just want to go back to a version of Ubuntu that will work!

Comment: If Dell customer service already diagnosed an hardware failure, no software on Earth will make any difference. And Verizon? Isn't that an ISP? It makes as many sense to call them about your PC issue than about you car issue, i.e., makes no sense at all.

Comment: IF you don't leave it for more than 5 minutes does it keep working all day and night? Does it shut off or does it suspend? Have you looked at the power settings menu to see if it's set to lock or suspend after 5 minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 2):

In your launcher click on `System Settings`, then pick the `Power` icon. A screen like this appears:

[image]

If it says to suspend when inactive for 5 minutes when plugged in click the down arrow and change the value to `Never`.

Dell tech support may say you need a new motherboard when you really don't. The person on the phone doesn't actually have to do the work. That said when my Dell laptop was new in 2012 many users got new motherboards and touchpads but in the end it was a BIOS upgrade that made it purr properly when I bought it used in 2014. Good deal for me getting a $2K laptop for $400. Not so good for the seller I guess.